# Is there a possibility to access a docker-compose container from another machine inside the local network?

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL2 Ubuntu with Docker CE and Docker-Compose.

I want to access the containers I'm running (mostly Apache/MySQL/Wordpress containers) from my local network (sometimes same, sometimes other machines).

For example:

PC1: 192.168.178.20

PC2: 192.168.178.21

On PC1 is Windows + WSL2-Ubuntu with all the docker containers.

I want to access the containers from the Windows-Browser (Chrome) but also from the browser from PC2 (also Chrome, for mac).

Is this even possible? If yes, how?

I got webpack to work with hot reload from WSL2 but this seems very hard and I don't know where to start.

Is it possible to add DNS-Names for specific containers in my router? for example if you call "example.test" my router forwards to the IP from the Docker-Box?

Comment: You need to expose container ports in `docker-compose.yml` and configure firewall to allow connections for those ports.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions, some better than others.

1. Find the port number that your container is **MAPPED** to your host machine (PC1) and make sure you can browse that way.  Then take the same URL to PC2 and try it out and see if it works.  Make sure you are using the Fully Qualified Domain Name or IP address so it is resolved to find PC1.
2. Find the port number that your container is **EXPOSED** to your host machine (PC1) and make sure you can browse that way.  Repeat the process as above.
3. Use a reverse proxy.  I am biased and will say to use Traefik because of its relative simplicity (compared to nginx) to configure.  It is just another container.  It uses RULES (combination of URL Header, Port Number, Path, etc.) to route incoming connections to services/containers.  In your case you will create a rule of URL Header (webapp1.corp.com) and port number (80) and route it to a **specific** container you have running.  Then from either computer browser enter http://webapp1.corp.com the connection will be routed to the specific container.  This is a very simplistic answer that is more complicated but you should get the gist.

You mentioned you are running multiple containers, so I recommend you use docker-compose if you aren't already using it.

Comment: usecase 3 is exactly what I'm looking for but how does the connection from other machine to the WSL2 machine works if I there is no hosts-change or dns change in router?

Comment: You can make a DNS entry to the router so that webapp1.corp.com resolves to PC1 IP address, OR create a rule that still uses PC1's fully qualified name as well as a unique port number (for example 85), OR create a rule that still uses PC1's fully qualified name as well as a PATH (`http://pc1.home.com/somepath`) that will redirect to the specific container.  OR manually edit PC1 and PC2 `hosts` file to map "webapp1.corp.com" to PC1 ip address that will resolve the URL  .There is just many ways and rules that can be created to route the connections to the container.